# Access item info when it's clicked on a table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table where when I click on a item a dialog pops up.

```html
<template v-slot:body="{items}">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item,idx) in items" @click="dialog=true" :key="idx">
      <td v-on:click.stop>{{item.nick}}</td>
      <td v-on:click.stop>{{item.cat}}</td>
      <td v-for="(header,key) in dayNumbers" :key="key">{{item[header]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="400px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class="headline">Edit shift</span>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container>
          <v-form>
            <v-text-field label="Day" type="text" v-model="day" readonly></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field label="Name" type="text" v-model="nick" readonly></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field label="Shift" type="text" v-model="shift"></v-text-field>
            <v-checkbox v-model="def" label="Approved"></v-checkbox>
          </v-form>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog=false">Close</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" type="submit" @click="save">Save</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

I need to access to some data within the dialog. The value of the first field of the row (nick), the value of the item itself,  and the value of the header the item is on.
But I don't know how to access to them.
The event click:row of Vuetify's v-data-table is not emitted when slot body is used.

Any help?

Comment: in @click event of tr you can store the index in component data, then in dialog, access the item at specified index

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the @click to the <td> and from there I am able to store the index of the row and the header with idx and key. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> The event click:row of Vuetify's v-data-table is not emitted when slot body is used

According to vuetify documentation [Simple tables api's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/simple-tables/#api) does not accept events but [Datatable api's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions) accept. All that can be done with datatable-api with CRUD actions using a v-dialog component. See the example below, Click Run code snippet and view in full page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    sort-by="calories"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat color="white">
        <v-toolbar-title>My CRUD</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider
          class="mx-4"
          inset
          vertical
        ></v-divider>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">New Item</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.calories" label="Calories"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fat" label="Fat (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.carbs" label="Carbs (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.protein" label="Protein (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          </v-toolbar>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
          <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
    </template>
          </v-data-table>
          </template>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        dialog: false,
        headers: [{
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          {
            text: 'Calories',
            value: 'calories'
          },
          {
            text: 'Fat (g)',
            value: 'fat'
          },
          {
            text: 'Carbs (g)',
            value: 'carbs'
          },
          {
            text: 'Protein (g)',
            value: 'protein'
          },
          {
            text: 'Actions',
            value: 'actions',
            sortable: false
          },
        ],
        desserts: [],
        editedIndex: -1,
        editedItem: {
          name: '',
          calories: 0,
          fat: 0,
          carbs: 0,
          protein: 0,
        },
        defaultItem: {
          name: '',
          calories: 0,
          fat: 0,
          carbs: 0,
          protein: 0,
        },
      }),

      computed: {
        formTitle() {
          return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
        },
      },

      watch: {
        dialog(val) {
          val || this.close()
        },
      },

      created() {
        this.initialize()
      },

      methods: {
        initialize() {
          this.desserts = [{
              name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
              calories: 159,
              fat: 6.0,
              carbs: 24,
              protein: 4.0,
            },
            {
              name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
              calories: 237,
              fat: 9.0,
              carbs: 37,
              protein: 4.3,
            },
            {
              name: 'Eclair',
              calories: 262,
              fat: 16.0,
              carbs: 23,
              protein: 6.0,
            },
            {
              name: 'Cupcake',
              calories: 305,
              fat: 3.7,
              carbs: 67,
              protein: 4.3,
            },
            {
              name: 'Gingerbread',
              calories: 356,
              fat: 16.0,
              carbs: 49,
              protein: 3.9,
            },
            {
              name: 'Jelly bean',
              calories: 375,
              fat: 0.0,
              carbs: 94,
              protein: 0.0,
            },
            {
              name: 'Lollipop',
              calories: 392,
              fat: 0.2,
              carbs: 98,
              protein: 0,
            },
            {
              name: 'Honeycomb',
              calories: 408,
              fat: 3.2,
              carbs: 87,
              protein: 6.5,
            },
            {
              name: 'Donut',
              calories: 452,
              fat: 25.0,
              carbs: 51,
              protein: 4.9,
            },
            {
              name: 'KitKat',
              calories: 518,
              fat: 26.0,
              carbs: 65,
              protein: 7,
            },
          ]
        },

        editItem(item) {
          this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
          this.dialog = true
        },

        deleteItem(item) {
          const index = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
          confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.desserts.splice(index, 1)
        },

        close() {
          this.dialog = false
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
            this.editedIndex = -1
          })
        },

        save() {
          if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
            Object.assign(this.desserts[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
          } else {
            this.desserts.push(this.editedItem)
          }
          this.close()
        },
      },
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to say I am indeed using the data table and not the simple table. The CRUD example uses the actions slot by clicking on the icon and showing a dialog with all of the items of row.
My intention is to click on an specific <td> and display a dialog with info about that specific item.

Comment: @barych you code show <td> tag which is simple tables. Datatable doesn't use that tag. Check my code